# How can i use git codes in my eclipse project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I'm fairly new to android development and I have a super noob question about eclipse and git projects . Well my problem is that I have imported a git project into eclipse but i dont know how to use it  . this is the project I've imported : https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView . I have no idea how to use the code though .

even though i did follow the instructions mentioned in the readme file , I couldnt get this thing to work . this is the instruction :

---

### Usage:

Place TouchImageView.java in your project. It can then be used the same as
ImageView. Example:

### TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

I did this but it didn't work . Sorry if my questions seems stupid , I'm a newbie :D

Comment: Do you have access of GIT into your PC? I mean are you able to create repository in any of your folder? If yes then you need to create new clone and in that you have to copy-paste the GIT url which is mentioned in https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView. and if you dont have access of GIT in your PC then you need to download the ZIP from the same URL and import that in your eclipse.

Comment: Why don't you just do what the author told you? Just copy [TouchImageView.java](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java) to your **own** Android application project and use it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'I couldnt get this thing to work' ?
Does it compile ? If not did you add the library dependency ?
Is it an exception at runtime ?
Please give more detail about your issues

Comment: @user3364136 see my updated comment.

Comment: Thanks Anddev . I followed ur instruction and imported the project succesufully , it works now :)

Comment: thank you still_learning I did that and it worked . although i had a few problems in copying the java class but finally I did . thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add EGit plugin to your eclipse IDE then get your github 
    code into your eclipse using this plugin..

```
For More Refrence :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html
```